# Can we preserve youth wearing a magnet?

Tags: medical-science, magnets

> According to Legend, Cleopatra wore a magnetic amulet on her forehead
>   to preserve her youth; this placement put it near the brain’s
>   magnetically sensitive pineal gland.

[Healing therapies](http://www.healingtherapies.info/magnetic_healing.htm) claimed that through [Magnet therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_therapy), it's possible to preserve youth and Cleopatra achieved that already. 
Is there any studies conducted on preserving your youth using magnet?

Comment: But then, the best way of preserving youth, is dying young.

Comment: possible duplicates http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/do-magnetic-insoles-or-bracelets-increase-muscular-strength-and-flexibility?rq=1 and http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/was-there-a-trick-behind-this-magnetic-therapy-demonstration?rq=1

Comment: quack sites as ways to give notability to a strange and dubious claim about a historic person surrounded in myth. Interesting...

Comment: If it really works, why isn't Cleopatra still with us?

Comment: "According to Legend..." means nothing unless the source is cited.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't found any study regarding the "youth preserving effect" of magnets, but in general :

**there isn't any proof that Magnetotherapy is better than a placebo.**

> Most of the many testimonials to the effectiveness of magnetic therapy
>   devices can be attributed to placebo effects and to other effects
>   accompanying their use.

from 
[magnetic therapy plausible attraction/](http://www.csicop.org/si/show/magnetic_therapy_plausible_attraction/)

and wikipedia

[Magnet therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_therapy)